# How to update collectionView in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to pass data from one collection View selected cell to another Collection View Label in same View Controller. here is my view Controller Code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    if collectionView == self.questionCollectionView {
        userPressedAnswer.append(modelData[indexPath.row])
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? AnswerCollectionViewCell
        //cell?.answerAlphabet.isHidden = false
        print(modelData[indexPath.row])

    } else {
        print("hello")
   }
}
```

[image: Here is my UI Screenshot]

Comment: `yourCollectionView.reloadData()` if it didn't work put it in this block : `DispatchQueue.main.async {yourCollectionView.reloadData()}`

Answer (score 0):

Save data to show for the dependent collection in view controller. The delegate should use this data for the collection. When a cell is selected in the main collection, update the data and reload collection with

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: How to set cellForRowAtIndexpath for the first collection view .because user continuously tap cell for the second collection view

Comment: @Md Munif Hasan I don't understand the question. What is a problem with your cellForRowAtIndexpath implementation? Just create a cell and return. How it's related to taps on the second collection view.

Comment: @Md Munif Hasan re-format the question above. What do you want to implement exactly? What problem you are facing?

Comment: because first collectionView data are coming based on second collectionView user taped data.So how do I set label data for first collectionView.plz give some useful resources/link/video from where I understand how to handle this kind of situation.

Comment: @Md Munif Hasan I think I already answered the question: "Save data to show for the dependent collection in view controller. The delegate should use this data for the collection. When a cell is selected in the main collection, update the data and reload collection with `collectionView.reloadData()`". Is something still not clear?

Answer (score 0):

In order to refresh data in collection view,after assigning values to the items of a cell you must do this:

```
self.collectionView.reloaddata()
```